# Display upcoming Calendar Events in Android Wear Watchface?

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, android-calendar, wear-os

I want to show calendar events (daily agenda) from specific calendars on an Android Wear watchface.

Is the [Calendar Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html) available for query in an Android Wear Watchface?

How do I make sure it stays in sync throughout the day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, the content provider is not available. Take a look into how to sync data in here: http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what info you need to look up. See WearableCalendarContract (though I don't think they've posted the JavaDocs yet, so I've only found a little info [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCcQFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplus.google.com%2F%2BDanWallach%2Fposts%2Fba1YkUgFXEN&ei=egGnVOD5JsmoyATD-4KgAw&usg=AFQjCNFLmnDmHXGig_k4efGfaSzFD7YCww&sig2=Pi463PEAMfHogZrTINpG1g&bvm=bv.82001339,d.aWw)). I'm able to, for example, get a range of event instances with this:

```
  long begin = _time.toMillis(false);
  Uri.Builder builder = WearableCalendarContract.Instances.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
  ContentUris.appendId(builder, begin);
  ContentUris.appendId(builder, begin + DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS);
  Uri instURI = builder.build();
  Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(instURI, INSTANCE_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
```

But my attempts at reading the event table to find out more about the instances haven't worked (note that the WearableCalendarContract doesn't include an Events URI). I've tried both authorities to no avail.